# Internal Server Error on Nextcloud instance migration from Debian 12 to Rocky Linux 9 server

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mariadb, nextcloud, rocky-linux

I've done everything by the book, according to the official guide, available here https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/maintenance/migrating.html

It is not a SELinux issue. I've tried putting SEL intro permissive mode, restarting the httpd, php-fpm, mariadb and redis services, and I've got the same issue.

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION: When trying to access the migrated instance from the web, this is displayed in the browser:

"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.
More details can be found in the server log."

This is the relevant error in the nextcloud log:

```
{"reqId":"Zc3t-mU9wVyFiRqbTb5fKAAAAJc","level":3,"time":"2024-02-15T10:56:58+00:00","remoteAddr":"<redacted>","user":"--","app":"core","method":"GET","url":"/","message":"Exception thrown: Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0","version":"28.0.1.1","exception":{"Exception":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception","Message":"Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver","Code":0,"Trace":[{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php","line":1654,"function":"connect","class":"OC\\DB\\Connection","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php","line":1081,"function":"getWrappedConnection","class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php","line":261,"function":"executeQuery","class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Query/QueryBuilder.php","line":341,"function":"executeQuery","class":"OC\\DB\\Connection","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Query/QueryBuilder.php","line":377,"function":"executeQuery","class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Query\\QueryBuilder","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/QueryBuilder/QueryBuilder.php","line":280,"function":"execute","class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Query\\QueryBuilder","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppConfig.php","line":418,"function":"execute","class":"OC\\DB\\QueryBuilder\\QueryBuilder","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppConfig.php","line":184,"function":"loadConfigValues","class":"OC\\AppConfig","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppConfig.php","line":374,"function":"getApps","class":"OC\\AppConfig","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/legacy/OC_App.php","line":734,"function":"getValues","class":"OC\\AppConfig","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/TemplateLayout.php","line":236,"function":"getAppVersions","class":"OC_App","type":"::"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/legacy/OC_Template.php","line":142,"function":"__construct","class":"OC\\TemplateLayout","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Template/Base.php","line":132,"function":"fetchPage","class":"OC_Template","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/legacy/OC_Template.php","line":291,"function":"printPage","class":"OC\\Template\\Base","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/index.php","line":104,"function":"printExceptionErrorPage","class":"OC_Template","type":"::"}],"File":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php","Line":139,"CustomMessage":"Exception thrown: Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception"}}
```

The database has been properly migrated, the user and password properly set up. I've checked, and the database is accessible from the localhost.

Here is some data on my new environment:

Rocky Linux 9.3 (Blue Onyx) x86_64

Nextcloud ver. 28.0.1.1

Web server ver. Apache/2.4.57

MySQL  ver. 15.1 Distrib 10.5.22-MariaDB

Redis server v=6.2.7

PHP 8.1.27

Zend Engine v4.1.27

Zend OPcache v8.1.27

[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt (built with pecl, the rest are EPEL-release packages)
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

Here is my /var/www/nextcloud/config/config.php

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => '<redacted>',
  'passwordsalt' => '<redacted>',
  'secret' => '<redacted>',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => '10.8.0.1',
    1 => '<redacted>',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/nextcloud',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '28.0.1.1',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://10.8.0.1',
  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbpassword' => '<redacted>',
  'installed' => true,
  'maintenance' => true,
  'updater.secret' => '<redacted>',
  'loglevel' => 2,
  'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'theme' => '',
);
```

Help me out guys, I'd really rather migrate my old instance instead of deploying a new one.

Comment: How did you migrate the database? How is set connection to database? Did you check if you can access the database with these credentials?

Comment: Dumped the old database to a file, transferred the file to the new environment, created a database with the same name, created a user with the same credentials, granted access to the database to said user, restored database from file. The connection is over unix sockets. I can access the database locally using the mentioned above credentials.

Comment: Did you install `php_mysql`? Because I read in the error you provide: **"Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver"**

Comment: I have the php-mysqlnd-8.1.27-1 package installed. I think it provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by completely uninstalling php and all modules from the EPEL repo, then installing PHP 8.3 and needed modules from the REMI repo. Now the web interface is up and running.

Comment: Could be interesting to have a diff of extension list (I suspect "sodium"), if available on old install, probably used to store passwords (so unusable on new install without this extension)